# MessageDialog closes unexpectedly with Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin.android

I tried getting some help from the Facebook Developers Group with no luck, so I'm hoping that someone can help me here:

I've had an app that has been using the MessageDialog from Facebook SDK to share through Facebook Messenger.  Its been working as expected for a year.  However all of a sudden it has stopped working (no code changes).  I tried upgrading to the latest version of the Facebook SDK that Xamarin supports, but that gave me some compile errors that I could not resolve.

From there, I created a brand new project from scratch that did only a Facebook login and the MessageDialog.  (In case it was something else in my application that was possibly interfering).  Unfortunately, it did not fix the problem.

I have filed a bug report with Facebook in case it is a bug, but they have not got back to me yet.

Has anyone ran into this?  Any ideas how to resolve?  I'll continue researching and post any findings here...

Thanks,

James

Comment: Update:  I was able to get the latest version of the Facebook SDK working from Xamarin as well.  However once I tested it I am still encountering the problem.  At this point I'm starting to believe this is a Facebook SDK bug.  I'll post if I hear anything back from their team...  In the meantime if anyone has any ideas...

Comment: Update 2:  Two others have joined my Facebook bug report, reporting the exact same thing.  One was reproducing the issue with a raw Java sample app that apparently Facebook provides.  At this point I believe it is a problem that many are experiencing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebooks latest update to Messenger has fixed this issue.  Update to the latest version of messenger.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has said they have now fixed the bug and it will be in the next Messenger release.  I've now asked them for an appx date.  I'll keep posting and updating here.

James